# why git-completion.bash is not autocompleting show-ref?

Tags: git

The git autocompletion has `show` and `show-branch` but not `show-ref`. Is this because autocompletion list is not complete? or is there any other reason?

[note] I am using the latest git from source (git version 1.7.5.128.g50d30)

Comment: in this blog entry [http://www.wincent.com/a/about/wincent/weblog/archives/2007/12/bash_completion.php] the show-ref is autocompleted. I will need to find time to look inside the bash code.

Comment: I think show-ref is plumbing, not porcelain

Comment: +1 @sehe. I didn't know about plumbing and porcelain concepts. Here I learn about it: http://progit.org/book/ch9-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come to think of it, that was the asnwer, of course:

> I think show-ref is plumbing, not porcelain

Porcelain can be used in various contexts including non-standard (overriden GIT_DIR, GIT_WORK_TREE, temporary directories, locks, whatnot). It would be ill-advised to use completion scripts indiscriminately during such operations, because they would invariably rely on other git subcommands, that may not exactly be valid at that time

This is my theory, people are welcome to supplement that :)